# Shapefile coordinate system

Tags: qgis, shapefile, coordinate-system, latitude-longitude

I added a shapefile of Iran to QGIS.

'Tehran' has 35.6833° N, 51.4167° E coordinates, however QGIS shows Tehran with 4772860,31296767.

How can I view coordinates of a city or location in latitude and longitude form in QGIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simpliest way is to set EPSG:4326 as Project CRS and check on-the-fly projection. If Qgis recognizes the CRS information in the shapefile, it wil place it in the correct position.

Please note that project CRS and layer CRS can be different, and have to be in your case.

Comment: after selecting EPSG:4326 for layer the coordinates does not change for cities and still remains as there were. how i check on-the-fly projection?

Comment: The CRS for the shapefile Layer should be EPSG: 32638, which is WGS-UTM 38N. You have to change the project CRS to EPSG 4326 under Settings/Project Settings. There you find also the checkbox for on-the-fly-projection.

Comment: @r.zarei, I had to remove the layer and add it in again, then everything worked for me.